# How to initialize a struct member with a function return?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I am trying to initialize a struct member with a function that returns a concatenated string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(char* dest, char* src) {
    strcat(dest, src);
    return dest;
}

char string1[15] = "hello";
char string2[15] = "world";

typedef struct {
    char* member;
} STATE;

STATE default_state = {
    concat(string1, string2)
};
```

This is the error message :

error: initializer element is not constant

concat(alphabet, digits)

Comment: https://www.educative.io/blog/concatenate-string-c

Comment: The error message is not about your `concat` function per se, it's about how you cannot call functions in initializers of global (file-scope) variables. Either make `default_state` a local variable or initialize it early in `main` or initialize it to a string that is known at compile time. Also note that your `concat` function will change `string1`, so using it later might lead to a surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization is done and computed at compile time. You cannot call a function at compile time. At compile time, the compiler needs to know the initializing value, but it cannot run any function.

Either delay the initialization at runtime, there you can call any function you want, or use immediate values that the compiler can use.

For example, using the fact that `"str1" "str2"` is treated ad `"str1str2"`, you could write this code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(char* dest, char* src) {
    strcat(dest, src);
    return dest;
}

#define HELLO "hello"
#define WORLD "world"
char string1[15] = HELLO;
char string2[15] = WORLD;

typedef struct {
    char* member;
} STATE;

STATE default_state = {
    HELLO WORLD
};
```